# using if else condition on checkbox html

Tags: html, laravel

I have quite same problems with this one,
[JavaScript - Using "checked/unchecked checkbox" as "IF ELSE condition statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589660/javascript-using-checked-unchecked-checkbox-as-if-else-condition-statement)
but mine is without button onclick. any idea what can i do for this?

this is my code:

```
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Category*</label>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="meti_d" value="METI Member - Domestic"> METI Member - Domestic
                      </label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="lec_d" value="Lecturer - Domestic"> Lecturer - Domestic
                      </label>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="meti_i" value="METI Member - International "> METI Member - International
                      </label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="lec_i" value="Lecturer - International"> Lecturer - International
                      </label>
                  </div>
                </td
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="pro_d" value="Professional - Domestic"> Professional - Domestic
                      </label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="stud_d" value="Student - Domestic"> Student - Domestic
                      </label>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="pro_i" value="Professional - International"> Professional - International
                      </label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="stud_i" value="Student - International"> Student - International
                      </label>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
```

here's my script:

```
<script>
    function category(){
         var md = document.getElementById("meti_d");
         var price_md = "IDR " + parseInt("2000000");
         var ld = document.getElementById("lec_d");
         var mi = document.getElementById("meti_i");
         var li = document.getElementById("lec_i");
         var pd = document.getElementById("pro_d");
         var sd = document.getElementById("stud_d");
         var pi = document.getElementById("pro_i");
         var si = document.getElementById("stud_i");

         if (md.checked == true) {
           document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "IDR ";
         }
    }
  </script>
```

if i check one of the checkbox above, it will show prices in here

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="price">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you plz show us what have you tried that we could look?

Comment: What does your code look like currently?

Comment: I've edit it, thanks for remind me

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute onchange="category();" in your input tag like as

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="meti_i" value="METI Member - International ">
```